# How to fetch data from api in nodejs using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I am trying to fetch data from `api` to show in front-end.

My server-side code is -

```
app.get('/chats',function(req,res){
    User.find({}).exec(function(err,user){
          res.send(user);
   });
});
```

and in client side trying to fetch data this using code

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

   <script>
             $(function(){
                 console.log("response"); // not any response from here
                 $.get('/chats',function (data) {
                            console.log("reaches here"); // not any response from here
                            console.log(data);
                      });
               });
    </script>        

    </head>  
    <body>


    </body>   

    <html>
```

But the problem is that I am unable to fetch data from api.

Please, someone, help me with this.

Comment: Please write the error log. (@chrome: F12 - Console Tab)

Comment: It doesn't show anything.

Comment: Why are you using two jQuery libraries? Use only one.

Comment: firstly I tried `jquery-1.11.1.js` but it doesn't work. so I tried another but that also doesn't work.

Comment: If neither work, then your code that depends on jQuery will obviously not work. Open your [browser's developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and look for the cause.

Comment: @Mikey I know, So will you suggest me any solution?

Comment: Since your first `console.log()` does not even show anything, it appears your jQuery is not properly installed.  You will have to fix that first.  Probably the first thing to do is to open the console and see what error messages show there.  In Chrome, press F12, then click on the "console" tab and see what it reports there.

Comment: @jfriend00.as I mention it shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fetch() function :

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append("key","value");

var options = {
    method: "GET",
    headers : headers,
    mode: "cors",
    cache: "default"
}

fetch('/chats', options)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(response => console.log(response))
.catch(error => console.log("Error !",error));
```

This example get data (json format) from /chats